# Is it possible to make Gmail put incoming emails in special folders or labels automatically?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Is it possible to apply **filters** for incoming emails?

Let's say, if an email is coming from *sender1@site.com* with *infos* in subject I want it to go to the **infos1** label.

I don't want the filter to be based only on the sender, but on the subject too.

Comment: Yes...Just setup a filter.  I for the longest time sent email I recieve addressed to a particular email address I was forwarding to the account into a special folder.

Comment: Thanks! This is an **answer** not a comment :)

Comment: See also: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6579&topic=1669016&ctx=topic#0

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  Gmail filters can include multiple components and only flag/forward/tag emails that match the multiple requirements.

Some examples from my own filters:

`from:(removed@gmail.com or removed@removed.com) subject:("Delivery Status Notification")`

`to:(+special)`

The `to:(+special)` thing is an interesting filter.  Say your user is `sender1@gmail.com`.  You can give the email address `sender1+special@gmail.com` as your email address to someone, and all of your emails from that person (as long as they use the `+special` in the email address) will be filtered on that.